# Cocos2d: CCMenu Buttons for Retina Devices Have small touchable area

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

For the project I'm working on I'm doing the following:

```
CCLabelBMFont *howtoplayGameLabelFont = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"HOW TO PLAY" fntFile:font];
[howtoplayGameLabelFont setFontsize:fontSize];

CCMenuItemLabel *howtoplayGameLabel = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:howtoplayGameLabelFont target:self selector:@selector(startHowToPlay:)];

CCMenu *bottomMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:howtoplayGameLabel,creditsGameLabel, nil];
[bottomMenu alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding:padding];
[bottomMenu setPosition:ccp( size.width/2 + bottomXOffSet, size.height/2 + bottomYOffSet)];

[self addChild: bottomMenu z:10];
```

For non-retina displays the whole label is clickable, but for retina displays a really small section of the label is clickable.

How does one fix this?

Totally forgot I added code for setFontSize on CCMenuItemLabel. Here it is:

```
-(void)setFontsize:(float)fontsize
{
    Fontsize_   = fontsize * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
    self.scale = (Fontsize_ / OriginalFontsize_);
}
```

Comment: `CCLabelBMFont` doesn't have `fontsize` property. What did you do?

Comment: Forgot I added that code. I included that code in my post.

Comment: I bet the scale works for non-retina but doesn't work for retina.

Comment: I wonder how one controls the font size of labels in a menu?

Comment: You could also make a retina-sized font file so it will automatically use the up-scaled version.  It uses a -hd resolution similar to retina-enabled sprites.

Comment: I needed to double the conentSize for the labels. I fixed the problem.